# Complete reducibility, in linear algebra versus topology. The example of the translation representation of $\mathbb R$ in $L^2({\mathbb{R}})$

Tags: general-topology, fourier-analysis, representation-theory, fast-fourier-transform

On page 2 of [these notes](http://math.stanford.edu/%7Econrad/JLseminar/Notes/L1.pdf), the author provides an example of how a topologically reducible representation of a group can be lacking topological irreducibles. Before asking questions, I offer a simple introduction.

INTRODUCTION

Consider the representation of $\mathbb R$ on $L^2({\mathbb R})$ by translations $
 f(x)\;\longmapsto\;f(x\,+\,a)
 $
written as
$$
 {\mathbb{R}} \ni a\;:\quad f\;\longmapsto\;f\circ\hat{\cal{R}}_a\;\;.
 $$
An ${L^2({\mathbb R})}$ function can be Fourier-expanded as
$$
 f(x)\,=\int e^{\, 2\,\pi\, i\, t\, x}\, \hat{f}(t)\,dt\;\;.\qquad\qquad\qquad (*)
 $$
Since $\,f \in {L^2({\mathbb R})}\,\Longrightarrow\,\hat{\cal{R}}_a\, f \in {L^2({\mathbb R})}\,$, we can expand also the function $f\circ\hat{\cal{R}}_a\, (x) =f(x+a)\,$:
$$
 f(x\,+\, a)\,=\,\int e^{\, 2\,\pi\, i\, t\, x}\, \hat{f}_a(t)\,dt\;\;.
 $$
On the other hand, the insertion of $\, x+a\,$ instead of $\, x\,$ in (*) renders us
$$
 f(x+a)\,=\int e^{\, 2\,\pi\, i\, t\, x}\, e^{\, 2\,\pi\, i\, t\, a}\, \hat{f}(t)\,dt\;\;.
 $$
The former and the latter formulae, together, are indicating that the Fourier transform establishes an isomorphism between the translation representation of $\mathbb R$ on $L^2({\mathbb{R}})$ and the representation realised by multiplication by exponentials:
$$
 f(x)\,\longmapsto\,f(x\,+\, a)\quad\Longleftrightarrow\quad \hat{f}(t)\,\longmapsto\,e^{\, 2\,\pi\, i\, t\, a}\, \hat{f}(t)\;\;,\qquad\qquad\qquad (**)
 $$
so the Fourier transforms of $f$ and $f\circ\hat{\cal{R}}_a$ have the same support.

By Schur's lemma, an irreducible, if it exists, must be one-dimensional. This means that there is such a $t$ that (*) becomes
$$
 f(x)\,= e^{\, 2\,\pi\, i\, t\, x}\, \hat{f}(t)\;\;.
 $$
while (**) becomes
$$
 f(x+a)\,= e^{\, 2\,\pi\, i\, t\, x}\, e^{\, 2\,\pi\, i\, t\, a}\, \hat{f}(t)\;\;.
 $$
Combined, these two expressions yield:
$$
 f(x+a)\,= \, e^{\, 2\,\pi\, i\, t\, a}\,f(x)\;\;.\qquad\qquad\qquad (***)
 $$

Such a function, however, will not be residing in $L^2({\mathbb{R }})$.
Indeed, equality (***) enables us to write the squared norm $\,||\,f\,||^2\,=\,\int dx\,|f(x)|^2$ as
$$
 ||\,f\,||^2\,=\,\int da\,|\,e^{\, 2\,\pi\, i\, t\, a}\,f(0)\,|^2\,=\,|\,f(0)\,|^2\,\int da\,|\,e^{\, 2\,\pi\, i\, t\, a}\,|^2\,=\;\infty\;\;.
 $$
So the representation of $\mathbb R$ on $L^2({\mathbb{R}})$ lacks topological irreducibles.

At the same time, this representation is topologically reducible because it is said in [these notes](http://math.stanford.edu/%7Econrad/JLseminar/Notes/L1.pdf) that, for any measurable set $S\subset\mathbb R$, the vector space of functions $f$ for which $\hat{f}$ has support in $S$ gives an invariant closed subspace.

QUESTION 1.

Is there an elementary proof of the said fact that, for any measurable $S\subset\mathbb R$, the space of functions $f$ for which $\hat{f}$ has support in $S$ is an invariant closed subspace?

Since $f$ and $f\circ{\cal{R}}_a$ have the same support, the invariance holds, and the issue is closedness. To prove it, can we somehow use the fact that the Fourier transform is an isometry?

QUESTION 2.

Would it be right to say that the representation is completely reducible algebraically, but not topologically?

To put it simply, can we say that the sole exponentials, not being topological irreducibles, still can be regarded as algebraic irreducibles?

QUESTION 3.

Below come two definitions of complete reducibility.  Equivalent in linear algebra and in finite-dimensional topological vector spaces, they are not necessarily equivalent in infinite dimensions.

Consider a representation A(G) of a group G is a TVS (topological vector space).

$\quad$ Def 1
$\quad$ A(G) is topologically completely reducible if it splits into a (finite or infinite) direct sum of topological irreducibles.

$\quad$ Def 2
$\quad$ A(G) is topologically completely reducible if any of its topological subrepresentations has a complementary topological subrepresentation.

The representation of $\mathbb{R}$ on $L^2({\mathbb{R}})$ evidently does not satisfy Def 1.
(This representation simply lacks topological irreducibles.)

Since for any measurable $S\subset\mathbb R$ the space of functions $f$ for which $\hat{f}$ has support in $S$ is an invariant closed subspace, may we claim that the representation of $\mathbb{R}$ on $L^2({\mathbb{R}})$ satisfies Def 2  (and is completely reducible in the sense of this Def)?  What makes me doubt this is the presence of the word `**any**' in that definition. By considering all measurable $S\subset\mathbb R$, will we count **all** topological subrepresentations?

Comment: This question comes from our discussion at [MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/405127/complete-reducibility-in-linear-algebra-and-in-topology).

Comment: Question 1 can be shown a bit more abstractly: Show that functions in $L^2(\mathbb R)$ with support in $S$ is a closed subspace, and apply the inverse Fourier transform.

Comment: @Justauser Could you please check if I implement your idea correctly? **Step 1**  As Fourier transform is an isometry, the closedness of the space of functions f for which $\hat f$ has support in $S$ is the same as the closedness of the space of functions $f$ which themselves have support in $S$, without intervention of Fourier transform. **Step 2**  If $\chi_S$ is the (measureable) characteristic function of S then $1 - \chi_S$ is in $L^{\infty}$. So multiplication by it is a continuous operator on $L^2$.  Its closed kernel is the space of functions with support in S. *Are both steps right?*

Comment: @Justauser To be specific, I am not $100\,\%$ sure if the function $1−χ_S$ is in $L^\infty(R)$. Is it really? And if it is, is it really true that the multiplication by it is a continuous operator?

Comment: Another argument for why the indicated set is closed is in [my answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4273199).  As to [your proposed proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4273183/complete-reducibility-in-linear-algebra-versus-topology-the-example-of-the-tra#comment8894021_4273183), it seems to be fine.  Why wouldn't $1 - \chi_S$ be in $\operatorname L^\infty$?  It is measureable (directly from measureability of $S$) and everywhere bounded in absolute value (by $1$).  Once it is, $\lVert(1 - \chi_S)f\rVert_2 \le \lVert1 - \chi_S\rVert_\infty\lVert f\rVert_2$.

Comment: @LSpice Many thanks, again. Have to think this over. And I am ashamed to enquire what your imply by the subscripts 2 and $\infty$. Are these norms in $L^2$ and $L^{\infty}\,$?

Comment: [Yes](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4273183/complete-reducibility-in-linear-algebra-versus-topology-the-example-of-the-tra#comment8896210_4273183).

Comment: @LSpice And how to show that $|| (1-\chi_S)\,f  ||_2 \leq || 1-\chi_S   ||_\infty ||f||_2\,$?
Is this the Hölder's inequality? I am asking because in the standard formulatio of this inequality we have $||...||_1$.   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H%C3%B6lder%27s_inequality#Generalization_for_probability_measures

Comment: [Re](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/8896405), Hölder's inequality is for conjugate exponents ($p = 2$ and $q = \infty$ are not conjugate). The easiest way to prove the claimed equality is just to compute $\int \lvert(1 - \chi_S)(x)f(x)\rvert^2\mathrm dx$ and observe $\lvert(1 - \chi_S)(x)f(x)\rvert \le \lvert f(x)\rvert$ everywhere.  But, if you really want to use Hölder, then you can compute $\lVert(1 - \chi_S)^2 f^2\rVert_1 \le \lVert(1 - \chi_S)^2\rVert_\infty\lVert f^2\rVert_1$.

Comment: @LSpice $|(1-\chi_S)(x)\,f(x)|\leq|f(x)|$ everywhere $\Rightarrow$ $\int|(1-\chi_S)(x)\,f(x)|\,dx$ $\leq$ $\int\,|f(x)|\,dx$ $\Rightarrow$ $|| (1-\chi_S)\,f||_2\leq|| f ||_2\,$. How do you define $||(1-\chi_S) ||_\infty$ and how to utilise it, to obtain the final result?

Comment: [Re](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4273183/complete-reducibility-in-linear-algebra-versus-topology-the-example-of-the-tra/4273199comment8896967_4273183), as you say, $\lVert1 - \chi_S\rVert_\infty$ is the $\operatorname L^\infty$, or sup, norm.  The integral you write down would compute the $\operatorname L^1$ norm, not the $\operatorname L^2$ norm, but the argument is essentially the same.

Comment: @LSpice Should I have written it like this?
$ | ( 1 - \chi_S )(x)\, f(x) |  \leq  | f(x) |  $ everywhere $\Rightarrow$ 
$ \left( \, \int | (1-\chi_S)(x)\,f(x) |^2 dx \, \right)^{1/2} \leq \left(\,  \int |f(x)|^2     dx \,\right)^{1/2}    $    $\Rightarrow$  $ ||  (1-\chi_S)\,f  ||_2 \leq || f ||_2\;$. 
And you probably implied $  || (1-\chi_S) ||_{\infty} \equiv \inf\left\{ C\geq 0\,:\;|f(x)| \leq C\; \mbox{for almost every}\;x  \right\}\;=\;1$, correct?

Comment: [Yes](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4273183/complete-reducibility-in-linear-algebra-versus-topology-the-example-of-the-tra#comment8898507_4273183).  By the way, $\lVert f\rVert$ `\lVert f\rVert` spaces better than $||f||$ `||f||`.

Comment: @LSpice Thank you -- and also for the \lVert f\rVert commands. I have never seen them before

Answer (score 2):

Throughout, I'll write just $\operatorname L^2$ for $\operatorname L^2(\mathbb R)$; and, when I refer to it as a representation, will always mean to think of it as a representation of $\mathbb R$, with the regular (translation) action.

QUESTION 1.  Since the Fourier transform is a unitary automorphism of $\operatorname L^2$, it suffices to show that the space of functions vanishing on $S$ is closed in $\operatorname L^2$.  A sequence that converges in $\operatorname L^2$ has a subsequence that converges pointwise almost everywhere; so, if the original sequence consists of functions vanishing almost everywhere on $S$, then the limit function vanishes almost everywhere on $S$.

QUESTION 2.  $\operatorname L^2$ is neither algebraically nor topologically completely reducible, in the sense of Definition 1.  There are no irreducible subrepresentations of $\operatorname L^2(\mathbb R)$, algebraic or topological, because they would have to be 1-dimensional, hence spanned by a function $f$; and that function $f$ would have to transform under translation by a (necessarily unitary) character $\chi$, hence, if non-$0$, could not lie in $\operatorname L^2$.  As in our discussion at [MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/405127/complete-reducibility-in-linear-algebra-and-in-topology#comment1038526_405127), we would find that
$$
\int_{\mathbb R} \lvert f(t)\rvert^2\mathrm dt = \int_{\mathbb R} \lvert\chi(t - t_0) f(t_0)\rvert^2\mathrm dt = \int_{\mathbb R} \lvert f(t_0)\rvert^2\mathrm dt = \infty
$$
for any $t_0 \in \mathbb R$ such that $f(t_0) \ne 0$.

QUESTION 3:  I do not know (though I think it is known) whether all subrepresentations of $\operatorname L^2$ arise in this way.

Comment: So even an algebraic complete reducibility fails because this would drive the function out of $L^2$. What if we represent $\mathbb R$ in $L^{\infty}$ and consider the Fourier series as a formal sum, without requiring its convergence? (I know my question may be ridiculous.)

Comment: @Michael_1812, this is tangential, in some regards, but, amusingly, $L^\infty$ with essential-sup norm and translation action is _not_ a representation, because already the translation action of $\mathbb R$ on bounded continuous functions is _not_ continuous... e.g., due to the existence of not-uniformly continuous bounded continuous functions, such as $\sin(x^2)$. But/and this can be dodged in various ways... :)  Probably more robust to ask/think about tempered distributions for extensions...

Comment: @paulgarrett Tempered distributions for extensions.... Is this a way to extend the representations to spaces beyond $L^2$? Would a function satisfying conditions (***) reside there?

Comment: @Michael_1812, I will have more time to respond tomorrow, but, for the moment, you might google "Gelfand triples", one prototype of which is Schwartz functions $\subset L^2\subset$ tempered distributions. And "generalized eigenvectors", in that context. (Also, Weyl's notion of "generalized eigenfunction", a tangible precursor...)  More later.

Comment: @paulgarrett I see that you are pushing me towards quantum mechanics :)

Comment: @Michael_1812, wait, what? I thought it was modern number theory! :)

Comment: @LSpice Is my understanding correct that, whenever we are saying that S is the support of $\hat f$, we actually imply the closure of S? The [definition at Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Support_(mathematics)#Closed_support) says that the support of a continuous function $\hat f$ is defined topologically as the closure of the subset of $\mathbb R$ where $\hat f$ is non-zero.

Comment: Notice I avoided the word support, either for that reason or by luck, I don't remember.  The (topological) notion of support that you [mention](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4273183/complete-reducibility-in-linear-algebra-versus-topology-the-example-of-the-tra/4273199#comment8893991_4273199) is really only useful for continuous functions; for measureable functions, or rather their equivalence classes, it is better to speak of the [essential support](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Support_(mathematics)#Essential_support).

Comment: @paulgarrett Do you happen to know anyone who could answer my Question 3 ? (Alex Voronov, perhaps?)

Comment: @Michael_1812, I don't know a source or person off-hand for your Q3, but I would suspect that classical functional analysis books might contain such a result. Also, about support, it is possibly useful to think about support of a (tempered or otherwise) distribution, which, yes, involves a topological closure, rather than in terms of measure theory.

Comment: @paulgarrett Thank you for your comment!

Comment: @LSpice I am sorry to be such a dummy. Could you kindly clarify a point in your answer to my Q1 ? You demonstrated that the space of functions vanishing on S is closed in $L^2$. Therefrom, the space of functions having (essential) support on S will, too, be closed. This however is not exactly what I asked. What I needed was to show that the space of functions $f$ for which $\hat{f}$ has support in S is closed. I guess, the statement you proved is equivalent to mine via isometry. Could it be that if a subspace of $\hat{f}$ is closed then so is its preimage? How to show this explicitly?

Comment: [Re](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4273183/complete-reducibility-in-linear-algebra-versus-topology-the-example-of-the-tra/4273199#comment9465587_4273199), there is no such thing as "a subspace of $\hat f$", but I know what you mean.  Yes, if a space (or set) is closed, then its continuous preimage is closed; this is one of the definitions of continuity.

Comment: @LSpice Yes, indeed. Thank you